# Validate and display error messages for fields not in model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

For fields like Retype Password, Accept Terms and Conditions what is the best strategy to validate these fields both on the server and the client?

Comment: Why are these fields not in the model?  Maybe you should create a ViewModel containing all the fields on the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `DataAnnotations` and add the required, or other validation attributes. Then I use jQuery (or MS Validation) for client side. All is generated if you do it this way.

If you have fields that are not in your regular model, I create new "view" models that match the view. Make your life easier and do this!